# Apply a list of regex patterns over a string and return matches found

Tags: python, regex, list, loops

I am having multiple regex and I need to match all of them against the single line and need to find out witch regex got matched.

```
import re
re_list=['a',' b','c','\s+d']
str="a uuu d e 1 2 3"
re_pattern = re.compile( '|'.join( re_list) )

m=re.search(re_pattern, str)
```

But this does not work. I am looking to get a dictionary mapping the pattern to the substring matched.

```
{"a" : "a",
"\s+d": " d"}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, compile your patterns:

```
import re
ps = [re.compile(p) for p in re_list]
```

Now, you can iterate over them:

```
d = {}
for p in ps:
    # `string` is your string. Please don't use `str` to name variables.
    m = p.search(string)
    if m:  
        d[p.pattern] = m.group()

print(d)
{'a': 'a', '\\s+d': ' d'}
```

You *could* do this with a list comprehension

```
dict((p.pattern, p.search(s).group()) for p in ps if p.search(s))
```

But you would have to search twice, which is wasteful. You can avoid this by running a loop over the patterns instead, as I've shown above.